# AHCI, Windows 7 and can only boot with Windows DVD present

Tags: windows-7, ahci, bootmgr

Foolishly, I installed Windows 7 with my new SSD set to IDE. I would like to change it to AHCI. I have done this before, with a different motherboard.

What happens:

- I set the controller to AHCI in the BIOS; I also check correct boot order
- On boot, I get the 'BOOTMGR not found' error
- I use the Windows Recovery Console on the DVD
- Diskpart etc can see the disks, and bootrec claims to have rewritten the MBR/bootloader
- I reboot, same problem
- Recovery Console again and it detects a problem, fixes, reboots
- Recovery Console again and it detects the OS, and a problem - fixes, reboots
- I ignore the 'press any key to boot from DVD' prompt
- Windows boots fine
- I restart without the DVD and I'm back to square one

That optional 'press a key to boot from DVD' stage is something that the recovery process introduces - normally you have to choose to boot to the DVD at the BIOS stage. You also see this when installing Windows. I suspect that whatever temporary state that is is compatible with AHCI - but not the standard it returns to.

I have done the msahci/iaStorV registry hacks to no avail (this worked with the previous board). I can put it back to IDE where normal service is resumed. The board is an Asus M5A99X, the southbridge is AMD SB950, and this is Windows 7 x64. I would quite like not to have to reinstall it again.

Any ideas as to what I can do as a permanent fix?

Comment: So changing the registry key in msahci doesn't work? I have NEVER seen this fail to function.

Comment: Nope. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\msahci and its value Start is set to 0. Same for iaStorV. There are other related keys like amdsata but I don't know what the state should be, so haven't changed them.

Comment: I would add this as the answer but I can't yet: I appear to have fixed this by performing the same type of registry fix to:  
  
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\amdsata .  

O Bilal's post in this [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/changing-from-raid-to-ahci/4c94f678-6bd1-48a6-b871-8872c841023a?page=2) provides some clues.  
  
I don't know if this is an artifact of my driver installation order or just something that would have always happened, but hopefully it will help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have fixed this by performing the same type of registry fix to:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\amdsata`

In which the value of Start must be set to 0.

O. Bilal's post in this [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/changing-from-raid-to-ahci/4c94f678-6bd1-48a6-b871-8872c841023a?page=2) provides some clues - others may find they need to do something similar for NVidia drivers, for example.

I don't know if this is an artifact of my driver installation order or just something that would have always happened, but hopefully it will help someone.